# FOSRestBundle with QueryParam or ParamConverter not working

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I'm having a problem with FOSRestBundle. Everything was working fine, until I added the @QueryParam annotation (on my `cgetAction` method) and the @ParamConverter annotation (on my `getAction` method). I have no idea what could be wrong, but the error I'm getting back is this...

`The format "" is not supported for deserialization.
415 Unsupported Media Type - UnsupportedMediaTypeHttpException`

The point of failure so to speak is here:

`vendor\friendsofsymfony\rest-bundle\FOS\RestBundle\Request\AbstractRequestBodyParamConverter.php at line 118`

My annotations for the specific controller are as follows (I'm just posting the `cgetAction` as I'm sure they are related somehow, I just don't know how)

```
/**
 * Lists all School entities.
 *
 * @QueryParam(name="page", requirements="\d+", default="1", description="Current page of school listing")
 * @View(template="LMSSchoolBundle:School:index.html.twig", templateVar="pagination")
 */
public function cgetAction(ParamFetcher $fetcher)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('LMSSchoolBundle:School')->createQueryBuilder('s');

    $pagination = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate(
        $entities,
        $fetcher->get('page'),
        $this->container->getParameter('page_item_limit')
    );

    $groups = ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_API')) ? 'restapi' : 'standard';

    $view = $this->view($pagination)
                 ->getSerializationContext()
                 ->setGroups($groups);

    return $view;
}
```

And finally, the fos_rest section of my config.yml:

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        include_format: false
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
        validate: true
        validation_errors_argument: validationErrors
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener:
        decoders:
            json: fos_rest.decoder.jsontoform
            xml: fos_rest.decoder.xml
    allowed_methods_listener: true
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_API
    view:
        formats:
            json: true
            rss: false
            xml: true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: twig
        view_response_listener: 'force'
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/css', priorities: [ 'css' ], fallback_format: false, prefer_extension: true }
            - { path: '^/js', priorities: [ 'js' ], fallback_format: false, prefer_extension: true }
            - { path: '^/', priorities: [ 'html', 'json', 'xml' ], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
            - { path: '^/', host: 'api.%domain%', priorities: [ 'json', 'xml' ], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
```

NOTE - The `^/css` and `^/js` rules are in there because the bundle was messing with my layouts and such, don't know if that's the proper way to do it? I really don't know if this whole config section is even correct! The documentation is pretty complex, IMHO.

Anyway, if I remove the `@QueryParam` annotation, it continues into the function without an issue. But if I add it, the application exits before it even reaches `$em = $this->...`

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT** Oh and by the way, I have thought of the fact that this could be related to the JMSSerializer, but the website seems to be down at the moment (in South Africa at least), so yeah...